# Knowledge Management - HTML vs. Rich Text vs CSS

Tags: css, html, knowledge

We have thousands of articles. These articles will be eventually public facing on a website.

We need our internal Knowledge Management Moderators to be able to easily revise, update and upload revisions across articles.  HTML makes this too hard for moderators with no IT background.  Rich Text Editor would not be visually appealing when put on an external public facing website.  Is the solution CSS or a hybrid of CSS/HTML?

How do we make it very easy for non IT types to update/revise/upload across articles and still appear visually pleasing on a website/email attachment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We do exactly the same and the solution is a hybrid of CSS on the visualforce that exposes the articles and basic training on using the rich text editor. We also have changed the internal view to match the external view so that users can see immediately how their changes will look externally.